# Headers for `iz` and such in key=value format?

Tags: radare2

In [the MegaBeets tutorial, *"A journey into Radare 2 – Part 1: Simple crackme"*](https://www.megabeets.net/a-journey-into-radare-2-part-1/) the authors `iz` has,

```
vaddr=0x08048700 paddr=0x00000700 ordinal=000 sz=21 len=20 section=.rodata type=ascii string=\n .:: Megabeets ::.
```

Etc, However, my `iz` shows only,

```
000 0x00000a44 0x5647c37a7a44  20  21 (.rodata) ascii \n  .:: Megabeets ::.
```

Is there a way to get the extra information, namely the `keys=value` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version was used by [Megabeets](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/18698/megabeets) for this article but this output format output was changed in this [commit](https://github.com/radare/radare2/commit/e5734c008efa925b752519709341c2ddd82dd9a5).

You can change this `#if 0` locally and rebuild or you can use `json` format to get the "headers" - `izj~{}`, but in this format strings will be base64 encoded.

```
{
 "vaddr": 4294987551,
 "paddr": 20255,
 "ordinal": 76,
 "size": 5,
 "length": 4,
 "section": "4.__TEXT.__cstring",
 "type": "ascii",
 "string": "JTVzIA=="
},
{
 "vaddr": 4294987556,
 "paddr": 20260,
 "ordinal": 77,
 "size": 6,
 "length": 5,
 "section": "4.__TEXT.__cstring",
 "type": "ascii",
 "string": "JSpqZCA="
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers for `iz` have since been added back

```
[Strings]
Num Paddr      Vaddr      Len Size Section  Type  String
000 0x00000850 0x00000850  20  21 (.rodata) ascii \n  .:: Megabeets ::.
001 0x00000865 0x00000865  22  23 (.rodata) ascii Think you can make it?
002 0x0000087c 0x0000087c   9  10 (.rodata) ascii Success!\n
003 0x00000886 0x00000886  21  22 (.rodata) ascii Nop, Wrong argument.\n
```